# Why my website does appear blank on Apple devices?

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone

I made a website (http://anrsealed.com/). It works fine on Windows (Windows 7 on PC) and on Android (KitKat phone), but it appears as a blank page on Iphones. I have no Apple devices to test my website but I hopped it would work on all systems (Windows, Android, Apple). This website is a simple generator of files for a card game.

These are the languages and plugins I used to make it :

- HTML5
- Javascript

  - JQuery
  - Bootstrap v3 : To place things "easily"
  - Mustache JS : To generate dynamic views
  - Ajax : To load JSON files
  - JSZip : To create and zip files
  - FileSaver : To download the zipped files

Here is what should appear when it works on Windows and Android :

[image]

Could you help me to find what I made wrong to not work on Apple devices ?

Thank you for your answers.

Comment: Nice picture - but it's source code that we need. Please read this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: There is probably an error being thrown in an early loaded script which causes everything following to fail, did you get any console messages sent to you with the bug reports?

Comment: I should copy/paste all the code ?

Comment: Are you using WKWebView?

Comment: @PaulS. : I have no Apple device to test. A friend with an iPhone said me the site was blank.

Comment: @mechdon : No I don't use that.

Comment: I think you need to borrow an iPhone or an iPod Touch to run some tests and check if it really is not working. Just pasting all the code will not help. Also, I just checked the site on an old iPhone 3G running iOS 4 and the site displayed fine although no cards were displayed compared to using Safari on Mac OS X.

Comment: I guess what your friend mean by blank page is: when click on Generate & Download a new tab is open and a blank page is showing. Because Iphone cant handler zip file (if no app is installing for handler zip file) so nothing happen.

Comment: @RoboticCat : The images does not appear on you iPhone, but it works on Mac ?

Comment: Addition to my previous comment, the site is showing fine on Iphone 6.

Comment: On the Mac I get a load of images and text. On an *old* version of iOS I only get text plus the generate button. I didn't tap generate on either Mac or iPhone so @highqweb may be correct it's about what happens after tapping `generate`

Comment: Confirming @RoboticCat on iPhone 4 (iOS7).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FileSaver.js is not compatible on MAC/Safari. MAC/Chrome works.